# chemnum package

Tags: cross-referencing, chemnum

The following minimal code using the `chemnum` package was designed to replace TMP1, TMP2 and TMP3 in an eps file made by ChemDraw by numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\newenvironment{scheme}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}
    \cmpdref{ref:nucleophile1}
    \cmpdref{ref:nucleophile2}
    \cmpdref{ref:nucleophile3}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{aziridineopening}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

A copy of the eps file can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3094875/aziridineopening.eps). Is this problem due to my eps file or my code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Perhaps consider picking a more memorable user name that `user1281358` :-) For me, your example works as expected: could you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the file list you get into the question?

Comment: Also a chemistry comment about the scheme. Your arrow is coming from **1**, but in the text you indicate that **1** is added after some initial step. Unless you use two separate equivalents of **1**, that is misleading.

Comment: The log file can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3094875/minimum.log). I don't have a lot of experience with latex, so I looked over this one at first: `Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.` Could this be of any importance? By the way the schema was taken literally from a peer-reviewed article.

Comment: I see you are running on Windows, and that the log claims that the auxiliary compilations have failed. Could you try using `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` and see if that helps? `pdfcrop` is not always successful on Windows, at least for me.

Comment: Oh: I added `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to make it work.

Comment: No, that won't work for what you want. To get the substitution to work you need to do it with the `.eps` files.

Comment: Using `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` did not help.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks! `\usepackage{epstopdf}` was deleted and `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` was used. Hopefully I can make it work in the real file.

Answer (score 4):

(Summarising my comments into an answer.)

The most common issue when using `auto-pst-pdf` is a failure of the conversion after the LaTeX run. Here, in the log we find

```
Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
    Creation of minimum-pics.pdf failed.
This warning occured on input line 124.
```

As the file compiles without errors with pdfLaTeX, the most likely explanation is that `pdfcrop` is failing to run: this is the final step of the conversion process. In particular, `pdfcrop` will not work 'out of the box' on Windows. Thus a solution may well be to use

```
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
```