# No visible images in PDF: MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Tags: pdftex, ghostscript, auto-pst-pdf, chemmacros, pstool

Recently, I was forced to reinstall my MikTeX distribution. Now, in documents that compile without an actual tex error, there are missing graphics that I have included as eps-files. The following error, however, appears:

MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1.

I am using `pdflatex` in conjunction with the `auto-pst-pdf` package to be able to use eps-graphics in `pdflatex`.

I installed the following version: basic-miktex-2.9.5105-x64, all packages were updated today. However, I have also tried the x32 version, with the same result.

Unfortunately, I am not really able to locate the problem and produce a MWE. It seems like deleting parts of the document makes the graphics appear, and, more importantly, adding more graphics makes the document not compile without an error anymore, even though I am sure that the exact same document compiled nicely when I used my initial configuration.

I have read the related questions:

[auto-pst-pdf throws 'MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186255/auto-pst-pdf-throws-miktex-gpl-ghostscript-9-05-unrecoverable-error-exit-code)

[Ghostscript 8.57: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119280/ghostscript-8-57-unrecoverable-error-exit-code-1)

However, they don't mention missing images or similar things.

Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

---

Interestingly, the document compiles with `latex` without any errors and all images are displayed. With `pdflatex` i don't see the images, but get the warning that the floats are way too large for the page.

In the meantime, I have also installed tex-live and other versions of miktex, all of them leading to the same error.

---

As has been pointed out in the comments, `auto-pst-pdf` is not necessary to be able to use eps files with pdflatex. Switching from this package to `epstopdf` solves part of the problem: The document compiles without errors and all graphics are included. However I would like to be able to use `psfrag` on my figures. When I do so with `epstopdf` the tags are not replaced, i.e. i **need** to use `auto-pst-pdf` or `pstool` (see below).

---

I was able to produce a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scaled=.83]{beramono}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\selectchemgreekmapping{newtx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup[nmr]{
  delta = (ppm) ,
  pos-number = side ,
  use-equal,
  format = \bfseries,
  list=true ,
  coupling-nuclei-pre = { },
  coupling-nuclei-post = { } ,
  coupling-pos = sub,
 % coupling-pos-cs = \ensuremath , % <<< added
  atom-number-cs = \ensuremath    % <<< added
}
\sisetup{
  separate-uncertainty ,
  per-mode = symbol ,
  range-phrase = -- ,
  detect-mode = false ,
  detect-weight = true ,
  mode = text ,
  text-rm = \libertineLF % use libertine with lining figures
}

\begin{document}

Testing psfrag:
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\psfragfig*[scale=1.0]{./intro/test}{\replacecmpd[tag=test]{test}\replacecmpd[tag=rrr]{rrr}}  
\caption{Test}\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

It seems that `chemmacros` is producing the error, because if a remove it, all tags are replaced correctly. I get exactly the same error if i use `auto-pst-pdf` instead of `pstool`.

---

Here is a dropbox link of all files used and created during compilation:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jtxchech4r20pfw/AACHdaxVNyzgQi-uT3CABFGka?dl=0

Comment: Did you try Herbert's solution for the problem with `auto-pst-pdf`? Are you using TiKZ/PGF?

Comment: Yes, i tried what Herbert suggested, but without success.

Comment: Try converting the files at the command line. You might get more informative output.

Comment: What exactly do I need to do for that?

Comment: Er... on Windows? I don't know. I know you can do it. But I have no idea how. (But somebody else will.)

Comment: You don't need auto-pst-pdf if you only want to include eps graphics. Try `\usepackage{epstopdf}` instead. Or convert the graphics with `epstopdf` to pdf before use.

Comment: You can install latest version of `Ghostscript` on your system (v. 9.15) and the excellent [epspdf-setup](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/epspdf-setup/) tool.

Comment: Dear Bernard, dear Ulrike Fischer, I have installed the latest version of `Ghostscript`, but this does not solve the problem. When I remove the `auto-pst-pdf` package and add `epstopdf`, the problem is gone and the image appears. However, in that case, apparently I cannot use `psfrag` anymore?

Comment: Installing an external ghostscript will not help as ps2pdf will use the internal ghostscript msg.exe (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214655/2388). Beside this: Without a MWE it is impossible to debug a auto-pst-pdf/ghostscript-problem (it is already difficult with a MWE - I would try to avoid the package and to create pdf graphics with some external document).

Comment: Dear Ulrike Fischer, when installing Tex-Live I got a recent internal ghostscript version, but this did not solve the problem. I will try and add a MWE in a few minutes.

Comment: Could you add the `.log` file what does it say ? Check if this Q helps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49370/chemnum-package. Did you add `-shell-escape` flag to `pdflatex` before compilation. BTW your MWE can be made more compact by removing unnecessary preamble packages and options to narrow down where the package conflict is, something like this `\usepackage{pstool} \usepackage{chemnum}\usepackage{chemgreek}\usepackage{chemmacros}` and pstool loads `graphicx` and `psfrag` no need load again. To test code _if possible_ add via dropbox `test.eps` file which you wish to add psfrag tags

Comment: I alway used -shell-escape during compilation. I added a dropbox link. Thank you.

Comment: replacing the `\psfragfig*` command line with `\replacecmpd[tag=test]{test} \replacecmpd[tag=rrr]{rrr}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{test}` as shown in [Section 9 Replacing Tags in EPS os PS files Page 19, Fig:4 of chemnum 1.1 2014-08-08](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemnum/chemnum_en.pdf) and replacing `\usepackage{graphicx,auto-pst-pdf,psfrag}` with `\usepackage{pstool}` works with pdflatex compilation properly on TeXLive 2014.

Comment: `chemnum` has a feature to replace tags in eps fig but uses `auto-pst-pdf` for underhood latex-dvi->ps2pdf compilation of `test.pdf`. may be the speedy underhood compilation by `pstool` is not supported in `chemnum` or vice-versa, no idea. see related discussion http://texwelt.de/blog/latex-und-chemie-5-nummerieren-von-verbindungen-das-chemnum-paket/. may be post a feature request at https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum

Comment: Dear texenthusiast, thanks for your suggestions, but using `auto-pst-pdf` does not lead to a solution. The problem is that the way you describe it, worked for me prior to reinstalling everything, now however it doesn't. I found that `chemnum` works with `pstool` and the problem is solved if the option `crop=pdfcrop` is used. Nevertheless, thank you for your help and time.

Comment: `chemnum` uses `psfrag` internally. Everything that works with `psfrag` will work with `chemnum`, too. Personally I use `auto-pst-pdf` for usage with pdflatex but `pstool` should work, too.

Comment: Sometimes `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` seems to be needed, sometimes also the option `runs=2` is required

Comment: @cgnieder I noticed sending `chemnum` `\replacecmpd` commands in `\psfragfig*` throws `Unrecoverable error, exit code 1` error and does not work as seen by Vlad030691 in his code snippet `\psfragfig*[scale=1.0]{./intro/test}{\replacecmpd[tag=test]{test}\replacecmpd[tag=rrr]{rrr}}`. It would be great if `\psfragfig*` plays well with `\replacecmpd` I think thats where OP was stuck. pstool is much better option for `psfrag` especially as seen by author http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11844/15717

Comment: @texenthusiast Does it work using `psfrag`'s `\psfrag` within `\psfragfig`?. `\replacecmpd` is merely an elaborated wrapper for `\psfrag`...

Comment: @cgnieder the code snippet `\psfragfig*[scale=1.0]{./intro/test}{\replacecmpd[tag=test]{test}\replacecmpd[t‌​ag=rrr]{rrr}}` works well with `[crop=pdfcrop]` in `\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop]{pstool}` finally. Thats what OP Vlad030691 also noticed in the above upvoted comment. So in conclusion `crop=off` and `crop =pdfcrop` are good options for `auto-pst-pdf` and `pstool` respectively with package `chemnum`. May be you can include this option in a example `Fig 5 : Using Pstool with chemnum example` in `chenum` manual. but these options work in case to case basis, users may use with caution